# How to make cqlsh to display text correctly?

Tags: cassandra

When I try to read from a Cassandra table I get what looks like binary output:

```
cqlsh 10.243.128.4 --debug -e "select enduser from test.cert limit 2;"

 enduser
---------------------------------------
                *7UDdnLg\x1135J"\x15%(
  \x10\x1c\x1aHa\x7fO\x19)1@3b\x17\x
```

I am not sure why this is happening. The other fields are displayed correctly.

Table def:

```
CREATE TABLE test.cert (
    enduser text,
    cert_id int
    PRIMARY KEY (enduser, cert_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (cert_id ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 1024
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

I have tried UTF8 encoding with the command line but it did not help.

Answer (score 2):

The CQL `text` data type is a UTF-8 encoded string so it just displays the data in the cell.

It looks like you've stored some data with hex-encoding in it. If you post examples of what the data should be versus how it is displayed, it will provide clues as to what's going on. Cheers!

Comment: The data is generated by cassandra stress as text. Not sure why it does not display correctly.